# Can I determine a monitor's real world position in DirectX?

Tags: directx, directx-11

In mutiple monitor system, the DXGI output could exsists multiple in a DXGI adapter. The first output should mean primary monitor. However, in dual monitor case, it can placed left or right.

I want to get this information. Not just primary or non-primary. To get the real world position of an output.

Is it possible?

Comment: Not DXGI, but you could use [`EnumDisplayMonitors()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd162610.aspx) in combination with [`GetMonitorInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @NicoSchertler It was good clue. The DXGI output has same value in its description, DesktopCoordinates. I didn't think its location is non-zero!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [IDXGIOutput::GetDesc()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174548(v=vs.85).aspx). The `DesktopCoordinates` in [DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173068(v=vs.85).aspx) has monitor's position informations. Its origin values, `Left` & `Top` is **NOT** always zero. Only origin of primary Output is always zero. If the Output placed at left, the `Left` should negative value.